CMake: Unix Makefiles generator works under VSCode but not on command line
I'm almost getting the hang of using CMake on Windows. I have installed CMake, I have installed MSYS2. Things are working under the CMake Tools extension under VS code. My chosen generator is "Unix Makefiles" and it works. But from the command line it does not work:
PS C:\Users\ken\Desktop\prog24\lldb-mi-main> cmake . -G "Unix Makefiles"
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
PS C:\Users\ken\Desktop\prog24\lldb-mi-main>

In case it's useful: my chosen kit is GCC 14.2.0.  More details:



How does the bottom image relate to the top? Is this an embedded Powershell terminal inside of VSCode? The reason why I ask is a normal powershell terminal will not have any environment setup for MinGW or any other compiler. Also if you run CMake from a msys2 terminal it should know were the compiler is however make sure you pick the correct terminal. There is a separate shell for each: https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/

Been a while since I last used MSYS2, but I think you need to run your command from the MSYS2 shell.

I'd also just switch to the Ninja generator.

@drescherjm: bottom is the setting for the CMake Tools extension.  Top image is the menu for the CMake:Select a Kit command.  Neither is a terminal window.  My quoted text is from PowerShell.

@LHLaurini: That sounds right, but the MSYS2 shell doesn't even know the cmake command, while PowerShell does! Now I'm really lost.

Are you running CMake inside a powershell window that is inside VSCode or not? If you are just running windows powershell from outside the VSCode any VSCode settings you may have made may not be applied depending on the cmake commands you execute.

You can install cmake using pacman in msys2. I have it installed. When you use CMake in a msys2 environment I believe it will use the correct compiler and compiler settings for that environment.

@drescherjm, When I run CMake within the terminal window under VS code, it can't find the generator "Unix Makefiles". Whatever beneficial settings the extension may be using, they have not been applied here.
